# Some leads not appearing in searches

Tags: email

I am having a problem with some leads not coming up in searches for the lead email address.
This has only recently started happening and I don't believe it was caused by any changes at our end, I can't think of anything which could have caused this anyway.

<strike>The lead can be found by searching for other details on the lead but the email returns 0 results.</strike>
Further testing reveals that you cannot find the lead through searching for other fields

Does anyone know what could cause this?
Would it be a bug with salesforce's search index?

Comment: do you see the leads/email in views maybe? Are the emails valid? Were the bounced maybe? is this hapening with all users? administrator?

Comment: The leads can be found by searching for other fields and there are no problems viewing the lead along with the email address. The emails are a mix of valid and invalid. Its happening with all users

Comment: I mean in "Lead Views" can you see the leads that do now show while searching?

Comment: Yes, they appear in the lists so you can browse for a lead and then try searching for it and it will fail

Comment: You mention "Some leads"? are these imported leads? what's different about these "Some leads"? if imported, did you receive the confirmation email?

Comment: The leads in question were probably all pushed through via the api and the web to lead service

Comment: Is this also happening by the Owner of the lead? as shown on the Lead information page?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4596/discussion-between-saariko-and-arthurguy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up reporting the indexing delay to Salesforce and they identified a fault and raised a service status issue

Answer (score 3):

Are you on the EU1/NA8/NA9? Per http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/status/ it looks like there may be a Search Performance Degradation, which would explain your situation.

**12:42 pm PDT : EU1 / NA8 / NA9 Search Performance Degradation - Update 2** 
The salesforce.com Technology Team has identified a fix for the Search performance degradation issue affecting the EU1, NA8, and NA9 instances. Customers may continue to experience delays in searching for changed or newly created content.

To minimize customer impact, the fix will be implemented this evening. The salesforce.com Technology Team will closely monitor Search performance in the interim.

Additional information will be posted to trust.salesforce.com when the fix has been implemented and verified.

**10:26 am PDT : EU1 / NA8 / NA9 Search Performance Degradation - Update 1** 
The salesforce.com Technology Team is working to resolve a Search performance degradation issue affecting the EU1, NA8, and NA9 instances. Customers may experience a delay in searching for changed or newly created content.
Please check the status of trust.salesforce.com frequently for updates regarding this issue.

**8:39 am PDT : EU1 Search Perfomance Degradation** 
The salesforce.com Technology Team is working to resolve a Search performance degradation issue affecting the EU1 instance. Customers may experience a delay in searching for changed or newly created content.
Please check the status of trust.salesforce.com frequently for updates regarding this issue.

Comment: I reported the issue to salesforce and they identified an problem at their end.
At the time of posting there were no reported issues on eu1 so I guess they backdated the status messages

Answer (score 1):

Have the leads been converted?  Converted leads will not show up in search, but they will still show up in reports.

Create a lead report that shows the lead status and filter by your search email.  Your leads should come up and the status will tell you whether the lead has been converted or not.

You can then resolve the issue based on what you find in the report.

1) Lead has status of Converted - That explains your issue.  Converted leads are not searchable.

2) Lead has NOT been Converted - If this happens, I would open a Case with Salesforce.  You have an issue that is very easy to reproduce.  Send them a link to the report, a link to the lead (can get this from the report) and explain to them your search criteria that is not working as it should.

3) Lead is not showing up in report - In this case, I would export your leads using data loader and find the lead you are looking for in the CSV.  Get the ID of that Lead and you can now view it in Salesforce.  Again I would open a case with support and send them the link to the lead and ask why search is not working.

I hate opening a case, but I have never seen #2 or #3 happen before so I don't know what else to do in this situation.  I believe you should get an answer back quickly because the issue is very clear and easy to reproduce, meaning you should not have a lot of back and forth with support.

Comment: The leads hadn't been converted. I have raised a case and it sounds like an indexing issue at their end.

Comment: That makes sense.  Let us know what you find out.  Very strange issue.